# NestJS returning always 200 even if end point does not exists

Tags: nestjs

I created new NestJS app, and defined the controller like this:

```
@Controller('/risks')
export class RisksController {
  constructor(private readonly risksService: RisksService) {}

  @Get()
  getRisks(
    @Headers('companyId') companyId: string): Promise<EmoRisk[]> {
    return this.risksService.getRisks(companyId);
  }
}
```

I'm calling to end point that does not exists: /risks/something

And getting HTTP response 200

Why I'm not getting 404 error ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.

I need to build the app each time before running it